# Deploying new contract in transaction MIX IDE

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, mix

I'm running into an issue whenever i try to create a new transaction with my newly created contract "richoCoin". It seems like its expecting the "Sample.sample()" contract.

How do I resolve this?[image: Mix IDE]
[image: rychoCoin.sol]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your scenario you have to create a transaction with your contract, you still have a transaction with the default contract which is called Sample

Comment: That's what I tried to do, though it doesn't let me.

Comment: next to the Default_1 scenario, if you click New Scenario usually it creates automatically transaction from user1 with your contracts. you can also edit the transaction by double clicking it and you should see you contract in the Edit transaction window, Contract field

Comment: You the best! Thanx a lot

Comment: yw, not very intuitive at first I have to say ;)

Comment: the get() and set() javascript functions in the Sample contract are 2 ways within a html page to interact with the contract.